# Quick find a field or method in Eclipse's workspace

Tags: eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I find it extremely useful to use the <kbd>Ctrl(cmd)</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> shortcut on Eclipse to find a member field or method in a class (and use it again to get the ones from the super class).

However, I would like to know if there is a similar way to quickly search in the project and/or workspace for a field or method you know the name of but not where it is (similarly to how it is done to find a type <kbd>Ctrl(cmd)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or a resource <kbd>Ctrl(cmd)</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

If is not available where can I request it?

Comment: By the way, maybe it's obvious, but I found it only today - if you're searching a member or a method, which name you don't know for sure - you should press ctrl+o, type asterisk (* sign) in the edit field and then type part of the name you are searching. So I mean it supports masks. It will search in current class only of course. Very helpful!

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`ctrl+o` (`cmd+o`) opens the quick outline where you can search for a method within the current class.
Pressing `ctrl+o` again extends the search scope to the complete class hierarchy.

Comment: Oh, man! Thank you for this! This was exactly what I was looking for! When working with code that I hadn't seen before, I often wished there was some way to see if from a class I had access to certain objects or not. This does exactly that! Thank you again!

Comment: the disadvantage is that you have to be in the class where the method was declared. Isn't there an outline grouped by class of the entire project. Just wondering!

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 35):

The closest thing I know of is the Java Search, which allows you to specify searching for a method, field, class, etc. If you're in the Java or Java Browsing perspective, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> will open the Search dialog with Java Search as the selected type.

If you want to request a feature or enhancement, enter it into [Eclipse's Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). Keep in mind that the backlog of feature requests is **HUGE**, so the most effective way to get yours noticed is to take initiative and submit a patch.

Comment: Yeah I know of that one, but given that the structure of the entire workspace is indexed (and hence the massive memory overhead among other things) I think this would be really helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure how practical a direct-search (ala `Ctrl+Shift+T`) would be for members; the number of members is probably at least 10x the number of classes in an average workspace. By the way, I'm pretty sure the entire index of Java is not in memory all the time.

Answer (score 3):

With the `ctrl+h` you will have some more options to search.

Under java search option you may find search for `type`, `method`, `package`, `constuctor`, `field`.

Also you may find "Limit To" option to narrow your search result and get precise search result!

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way that I'm aware of is by using `ctrl+h` to bring up the Java search dialog.

Comment: cmd+h hides the application on Macs ;)

Comment: @pablisco edited the answer and remove cmd+h to avoid confusion

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mac `cmd + shift + l` will open a search box where you can search for any variable or method through out the project.

Comment: Excellent! Note: `ctrl + shift + l` for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

`ctrl+h`  will bring up java search option. Enter your string and see. It also has different patterns like `.java`, `.jsp`, then select scope then search.

Answer (score -2):

There's no way to do this in Eclipse. When you search for a method that's in a JAR Eclipse will not find it unless you already had the folder open.

You have to play around with it and use indirect ways of finding the method.