# is there a shortcut for eclipse similar to "find members in current project" shortcut in intellij idea

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to list all methods in my **Eclipse** project and navigate to a specific method by just typing only some part of method name.

In **Netbeans** I can see the list of methods by using **"go to symbol - [CTRL+Shift+Alt+O]**" diyalog. 
**Intellij IDEA** provides similar functionality named as "**find members in current project - [CTRL+Shift+Alt+N]**".

I wonder if Eclipse has this functionality. If so, what shortcut should I use?

Comment: I think your question is simmilar to [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852256/quick-find-a-field-or-method-in-eclipses-workspace)

Comment: Yes, it seems similar but the answer is unsatisfying, I assume there isn't similar functionality in eclipse.